# React 16, React-Router, lifecycle methods are not invoked when url query parameter changes with respect to browser click

Tags: reactjs, react-router, back-button, url-parameters

To keep the state changes alive on browser refresh, I update the URL parameter with state variables. But the problem is in React 16 none of the lifecycle methods are invoked when browser back or forward button is clicked. URL will be updated but no life cycle method calls are invoked. One way to get this problem done was setting URL Query Parameter to prop of every Route. But this will invoke the Lifecycle methods when we switch Application/Browser Tab.

Is there any better way to get solve this Problem.

Answer (score 0):

React provides you the basic lifecycle methods that are required and we have to figure out how we can use it best. In your scenerio what you can do is. Just use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle hook and check if the URL contains the variable's that you have passed, if  they are present it means page is refreshed.

You can get the `params` by using `history` object or specifically `params` object of `react-router` library.

Comment: That works in Normal cases. But in Browser back and forward Button click, these life cycle methods are not invoked. If the route is changing Life cycle methods are invoked. Not URL parameter changes.

Comment: That's because you are not passing the parameters that may be required for your component to render. I can help you if you can share the code snippet and update the question.

Comment: When the browser back button click url parameter will be changed. But lifecycle methods are not triggered.

I will share the code.